# passing values from view to controller globally

Tags: angularjs

I am working on angularjs and faced a problem while displaying the details of each record on another page.The list of records are displayed using controller and each record has a link, on click of which i want to pass the id of the selected item to the same controller so that using this id I can display respective data.This is what i have done

```
<tr ng-repeat="doctor in doct| filter:name" ><td><a href=""  ng-click="showid(doctor.contactId)" >&gt</a><td></tr>
```

this is the code in js file:

```
app.controller('Mycontroller', function Mycontroller($scope,$http){



    $scope.showid=function(idPassedFromNgClick){
    var v=idPassedFromNgClick;
    console.log(v);

    $http.get('scripts/doc.json').success(function(data){
    $scope.doct=data;
    };
});
```

});

here i am passing the id in function showid. In console i am able to get the respective id.But i cant use it outside the scope of my function(showid).Plz suggest me a way to get it globally so that i can use it in details page.

Comment: what do you mean by you can't access it outside the scope?

Comment: means in the function showid itself i can use. Not globally

Comment: Well, if you want globally you can assign it to a global variable. $scope.showid=function(idPassedFromNgClick){
    Global_Var = idPassedFromNgClick;
}

Comment: thanx ya !! m done. i got it:)